# Adding hyperlink to existing image using Open XML SDK

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am struggling to work out a concise way to do what I'd imagine would be quite simple... I have a simple existing PowerPoint presentation with one slide and in it one image.

I want to programatically open this with the Open XML SDK (hosted in a .Net Core web application) and add a hyperlink to this, and save it... such that when it's reopened in PowerPoint, one can control+click on the image to visit the link.

```
        using (var ppt = PresentationDocument.Open("powerpoint.pptx", true))
        {
            var image = ppt.PresentationPart.SlideParts.First().ImageParts.First();

            // Code to add hyperlink to image here - a bit like:
            // image.HyperLink = "http://somewebpage"

            ppt.Save();
        }
```

Comment: Create a small (one slide) presentation with the image, but no hyperlink. Save it. Add a hyperlink and save under a different name. Open the first presentation in the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool. The use the "Compare" feature to open the second presentation. The tool will show you the code to turn the first into the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help from the comment from @Cindy Mester, I was able to strip down the suggested migration code from the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool to this:

```
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var original = File.OpenRead("withoutlink.pptx");
            original.CopyTo(ms);

            using (var ppt = PresentationDocument.Open(ms, true))
            {
                var slidePart1 = ppt.PresentationPart.SlideParts.First();

                var slide1 = slidePart1.Slide;

                var commonSlideData1 = slide1.GetFirstChild<CommonSlideData>();

                var shapeTree1 = commonSlideData1.GetFirstChild<ShapeTree>();

                var picture1 = shapeTree1.GetFirstChild<Picture>();

                var nonVisualPictureProperties1 = picture1.GetFirstChild<NonVisualPictureProperties>();

                var nonVisualDrawingProperties1 =
                    nonVisualPictureProperties1.GetFirstChild<NonVisualDrawingProperties>();

                var nonVisualDrawingPropertiesExtensionList1 = nonVisualDrawingProperties1
                    .GetFirstChild<A.NonVisualDrawingPropertiesExtensionList>();

                var relationshipId = "rId" + nonVisualPictureProperties1.Count();

                var hyperlinkOnClick1 = new A.HyperlinkOnClick {Id = relationshipId};
                nonVisualDrawingProperties1.InsertBefore(hyperlinkOnClick1,
                    nonVisualDrawingPropertiesExtensionList1);

                slidePart1.AddHyperlinkRelationship(new Uri("http://www.google.com/", UriKind.Absolute), true,
                    relationshipId);

                ppt.SaveAs("withlink.pptx");
            }
```

In order that I could edit the file without modifying the original I copied to memory stream and opened that - In my web app I can the stream this memory stream back to the client.